# Google Analytics Event Tracking Code causing uncaught syntax error

Tags: events, google-analytics

I am trying to use the following link to trigger event tracking in GA

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/2017-brochure-web.pdf" target="0" onClick=”ga(‘send’,‘event’,‘Online Brochure’,‘Download’,‘Product Brochure’,10);”>DOWNLOAD BROCHURE</a>
```

Console is giving me this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

any ideas what is causing that error?

Comment: The code you shared has varying single and double quote characters (`"` vs `”`, starting at the `onClick` handler. I'd at minimum make sure the characters are standard and consistent.

Comment: OK, that was totally it. Thank you so much. i retyped the code from scratch and now it works.

Comment: Great to hear. I created an answer to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark the answer that help you resolve your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This error is occurring because starting at `onClick` there are left and right single/double (`‘` `’` `”`) quotation characters rather than neutral quotation marks (`"`) and apostrophes (`'`). This can happen when copying and pasting from various sources.

Your code will work if you replace the left/right single/double quotation with neutral versions.

Hopefully that helps!